# Alternative proof of finite value of renewal function $m(t)$ when $t$ is finite.

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes

I came across this proposition in the book Stochastic Processes by Sheldon M. Ross,

$$
m(t) < \infty \ \ \ \ \text{for all }0 \leq t < \infty
$$

where $m(t) = \mathbb{E}[N(t)]$ is the renewal function i.e. the expected number of renewals by time $t$. The interarrival time of each renewal $X_n$ is iid with an arbitrary distribution $F$ such that $F(0) < 1$. Since $X_n \geq 0$ and $F(0) < 1$, the mean of the distribution follows $0 < \mu \leq \infty$.

Now, the proof of the proposition, as given in the book, defines a related renewal process $\bar{N}(t)$ such that $\bar{N}(t) \geq N(t)$ and shows that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{N}(t)] < \infty$ and therefore the result follows.

However, I couldn't come up with this trick and instead used the following argument to prove the proposition. In the argument below, $S_n$ is the arrival time of $n$th event i.e. $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.

- $t < \infty \implies N(t) < \infty$

  - This follows from the fact that an infinite number of renewals cannot occur in a finite time. The proof of this is as follows: by SLLN, $S_n/n \rightarrow \mu \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$. Since $\mu > 0$, $n \rightarrow\infty \implies S_n \rightarrow \infty$, thus $S_n$ can be less than or equal to $t$ for atmost a finite number of values of $n$. This argument is presented in the beginning of the chapter itself.
- $N(t) < \infty \implies \mathbb{E}[N(t)] < \infty$

  - This follows from the property of expectation i.e. $a < Y < b \implies a < \mathbb{E}[Y] < b$ which can easily be proved by using the upper and lower bounds in the integration (summation) used to compute expectation.

So, overall, $t < \infty \implies N(t) < \infty \implies \mathbb{E}[N(t)] < \infty$ and since $m(t) = \mathbb{E}[N(t)]$, it follows that, $t < \infty \implies m(t) < \infty$.

Can someone please verify this proof?